# A little misunderstanding on intent - android

Tags: android

In this situation:

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

I don't get why does the 'value' is that 'value'?
Eventually I just need the name "EXTRA_MESSAGE" for being a Key for some Value.
Why do we need the value to be inserted into the Key name?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the name "EXTRA_MESSAGE", you need the value for the variable EXTRA_MESSAGE..

You declare variable this way:

- public: so that it can be accessed from any class
- final: so that it shall not be overridden or changed by subclass
- static: so that it can be accessed without creating the object of
  class in which this variable is lies

You assigned value so as to keep consistency.

While sending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "");
```

While receiving:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Lets say, you don't declare this variable, then you will be using hard-coded string "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE" as arguments. If you mis-spelled argument extras key on either side, say "Com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE", your code won't work..

While sending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra("com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE", "");
```

While receiving:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getStringExtra("Com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"); // this won't work
```

Hope you got the point in declaring strings this way...!!

Comment: Still dont understanding :(..
So from the start you should send the value, but Java wanted to make easy things on you so you can "convert" the value to a short word?

Comment: @mklkj I guess you are not clear with Java Concepts.. Please take it on priority basis..

Comment: ill do that.. but before that. im right? Technically i need to pass the value.. but because i want a easy life so i make a constant that make my life easiar?

Comment: @mklkj Exactly.. But to be more precise, easy in terms of less error prone, more scalability,..